# How do I get pass this git error preventing a merge because some unknown local changes would be lost?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

When I try to `git pull` in my branch, I get:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    Vendor/JSONKit
```

Indeed, when I do a `git status`, it says Vendor/JSONKit is "modified".

Vendor/JSONKit contains a third-party project called JSONKit (https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit). I've never touched this code. I didn't set up the folder, either -- but I gather that it's what's called a "submodule".

What is causing this error and how do I get past it? If I try to `git stash`, it claims I have "No local changes to save." If I go into Vendor/JSONKit and try to do anything, git says I'm not on a branch anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single repository:

You should be able to explore the diff with `git diff -- Vendor/JSONKit`, but if you want to just reset the file (and abandon the changes), issue this command:

```
git checkout HEAD -- Vendor/JSONKit
```

That'll checkout the most recent version of `Vendor/JSONKit` in your working directory and abandon the modifications.

---

In a repository with submodules:

Git submodules allow you to embed git repositories inside one another. Suppose "JSONKit" were a submodule inside "MyApp". The top-level git repository, `MyApp`, only tracks the `HEAD` commits of `JSONKit`, so you can perfectly reconstruct both `MyApp`'s and `JSONKit`'s states at any point in history.

Suppose you committed changes inside the `JSONKit` repository. Inside `JSONKit`, this would look like a normal diff and have a normal history. Inside the parent repository, `MyApp`, it would register as a change to the `HEAD` commit. It might look something like this diff, taken from the [git scm docs.](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) The submodule in this example is a directory called "rack".

```
$ git diff --cached rack
diff --git a/rack b/rack
new file mode 160000
index 0000000..08d709f
--- /dev/null
+++ b/rack
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Subproject commit 08d709f78b8c5b0fbeb7821e37fa53e69afcf433
```

How does `MyApp` know which directories are submodules? It's tracked inside the `.gitmodules` file. `cat` it, and you'll see every submodule registered in `MyApp`:

```
$ cat .gitmodules 
[submodule "rack"]
    path = rack
    url = git://github.com/chneukirchen/rack.git
```

When you issued `git submodule update`, you told git to checkout the most recent `HEAD` commit for `JSONKit` in your parent repo's index, thus abandoning the change in the submodule repository:

```
update
   Update the registered submodules, i.e. clone missing submodules and checkout the commit specified in the index of the containing repository. This will
   make the submodules HEAD be detached unless --rebase or --merge is specified or the key submodule.$name.update is set to rebase, merge or none.  none
   can be overridden by specifying --checkout.
```

Comment: That didn't do anything for me for some reason. `git submodule update` fixed the problem. Do you know why?

Comment: Ah yes. Will modify the answer accordingly. I missed the submodule reference on your question originally.

Comment: @Aaron added information about submodules and submodule update. Apologies for the oversight.